# Как вывести значения в Combobox из БД?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Пытаюсь вывести значения как обычно, но выводит совсем не то, что я хотел бы.

[image: Вот так оно и выводит]

Код:

```
            database.closeCon();

            DB database1 = new DB();
            string query1 = "SELECT clients.Name FROM clients;";

            database.openCon();
            DataSet table1 = new DataSet();
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(query1, database1.getCon());
            adapter1.Fill(table1);
            comboBox1.DataSource = table1.Tables[0];

            database.closeCon();
```

Comment: Ох... Начните с подвига Геракла: очистка авгиевых конюшен. Зачем у вас `database` и `database1`? Зачем вы вообще нумеруете `table1`, `adapter1` - либо уберите номера, либо дайте им говорящие название. Зачем все эти манипуляции с открытиями-закрытиями соединений? Подсказка: DataAdapter выполняет их сам. Почему вы `DataSet` назвали `table1`? Почему не `dataSet`? Зачем вообще нужен датасет (набор таблиц), если используется всего одна таблица. Так и создавайте один `DataTable`.

Comment: `comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";` - задайте имя колонки.

Comment: Можете попробовать преобразовать полученный результат из БД в List<T>, где T - описанный вами класс. В конце концов, c# - это ведь про объекты. Создайте поля, свойства, конструкторы в этом классе и используйте нужные данные из класса для своего combobox. Например, из List с помощью Linq.Select вы можете выбрать нужное свойство и вставить уже IEnumerable<Y> в combobox